# Retrieving google chrome cookies using js

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to retrieve Google Chrome cookies, **Is there a possibility to do this ? how ?**

> **note**:
>   It's not for a bad reasons :)

Comment: -1 for not enough research efforts. See [`chrome.cookies`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html).

Answer (score 0):

Cookies is a part of web page so you have to use [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
Look at [xdebug extension](https://github.com/wrep/xdebug-helper-for-chrome/blob/master/source/content.js) as example